# Check if a specific named parameter exists or not in hibernate named query

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

I am trying to develop a application where I have a common DAO as EntityDao.

That class has a method executeNamedQuery as follows.

```
public List executeNamedQuery(String queryName) {
        Query query = getHibernateUtil().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);
        list = query.list();
        return list;
}
```

I have several named query in different classes. One example is given as follows.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "BookList",
    query = "FROM Book AS B WHERE cntrl1=:CNTRL_1"
    )
})
```

Aslo some of the queries does not have that where clause, or some of those have a where clause but does not have CNTRL_1 as named parameter.

I have a common CNTRL_1 value that I want to set from common EntityDao executeNativeQuery method with setParameter. But before that I want to determine is there any named parameter exists with name CNTRL_1 or not in the named query.

How to do that? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [getNamedParameters()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#getNamedParameters()) already?

Comment: Yes I found it just some time ago. Sorry, I did not noticed it is there. :). Trying to implement it now.